# Creating a raster of lines on a Terrain in Unity

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, terrain, vertices

I want to create a kind of raster of lines on a terrain. I want the user to view the terrain subdivided into squares.

I have a basic terrain and add the following Script as a component:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RasterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TerrainCollider terrain;
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        terrain = GetComponent<TerrainCollider>();
        float zStep = terrain.terrainData.size.z / terrain.terrainData.detailResolution;

        for (int i = 0; i <= terrain.terrainData.size.x; i+=2)
        {
            LineRenderer line = GameObject.Instantiate<LineRenderer>(lineRenderer);
            line.positionCount = terrain.terrainData.detailResolution;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.positionCount; j++)
            {
                line.SetPosition(j, new Vector3(i, terrain.terrainData.GetHeight(i, (int) (j * zStep)), (j * zStep) / 200));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`lineRenderer` is a `LineRenderer` I made a Prefab of, to instantiate it as often as I need. The idea here is to create a `LineRenderer` object every `i+=2` in the outer loop. I also tell the created line that the amount of vertices should be the detailResolution of the terrainData. Then I loop over every vertex and set its position via a new `Vector3`. As it is a nested loop, I do that for every `i (x value)`. However I think there is a problem with the `y` parameter of the newly created `Vector3`. The `y` parameter is the height, but somehow it is not identical to the terrain height.

The flawed outcome looks as follows:
[image: The height of the different line vertices and terrain does not seem to match]
The height of the different line vertices and terrain does not seem to match

The Terrain Object partially looks like this:
[image: important components of the terrain GameObject]

Where is the error in my algorithm?

Comment: I want to clarify something about your terrain image: does drawing start on the lower left corner and if so, does the line map match your terrain there?

Comment: Is your terrain scaled? Please set it to (1,1,1) and position it at (0,0,0) to make sure!